# Twilio TaskRouter: Add Another Agent in the same call

Tags: php, laravel, twilio, twilio-twiml, twilio-taskrouter

I am using TaskRouter. I am adding an inbound call to enqueue method like this

```
$enqueue = $response->enqueue('WSDSupport',['workflowSid' => $workflowSid,
                                                'action' => 'xxxxx']);
```

And Dequeuing the call like this on the assignment callback URL.

```
return response()->json([
            "instruction" => "dequeue",
            "Timeout" => "15", // to ring before assuming there is no answer
            "record" => "record-from-answer",
            "status_callback_url" => 'xxxxxxx',

        ]);
```

The task is created, the reservation is made and the call is connected to the worker successfully.
Now I am trying to add another worker in the same call without using conference.
If it's possible then how? If only conference is the only way then give me a rough idea how can I do that.

Answer (score 0):

The requirement of having more than two people on a call at the same time without using a Conference is not possible. To have more than two people on a call you must use a Conference.

To use a Conference, you first need to Dequeue the call to a Conference using the ["conference" instruction](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/api/reservations#conference). Then once you have an active Conference, you use the Twilio REST API Conference Participant to [Create a Conference Participant](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference-participant-resource?code-sample=code-create-a-conference-participant&code-language=C%23&code-sdk-version=6.x).

Comment: How can I convert the existing call to a conference without disconnecting any callers?
I don't want to use the conference for every call as it will be expensive.

Comment: For the additional cost, there are many benefits. To convert an existing call to a conference call you use the Twilio REST API and either the Conference or the ConferenceParticipant resources. All you need to do is redirect the call to Twiml that uses the Conference noun (https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/redirect)